# How to validate Alignment of text and web elements in page using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Alignment of text and web elements in a webpage Is there any way we can do validation for this? Googled a lot for the answer din't find anything ...Just want to know ...

Answer (score 0):

Using Selenium itself it can be quite trick, I would recommend considering using [Galen Framework](http://galenframework.com/) which allows automated testing of elements layouts at [pixel-perfect](https://www.quora.com/What-does-pixel-perfect-mean) precision.

Galen framework allows defining pass/fail criteria of the website layout using [simple declarative syntax](https://github.com/galenframework/galen-sample-tests/blob/master/specs/common.gspec) so you will be able to use Galen annotations in your test to introduce layout testing automation.

```
@objects
    header              id      header

= Main section =
    header:
        height 40px
```

References:

- [Layout Testing with Galen Framework](https://www.swtestacademy.com/galen-framework/)
- [The 7 Best Practices for Visual Testing with the Galen Framework](https://experitest.com/web-testing/the-7-best-practices-for-layout-testing-with-the-galen-framework/)
- [Galen Framework Tutorial - First Project](http://galenframework.com/docs/tutorial-first-project/)